Spark Driver out of memory due to communication with executors
My Spark Driver fails with OOM:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:141)
  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
  at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
  at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.toString(Collections.java:1037)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.accumValueToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:469)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.$anonfun$accumulableInfoToJson$7(JsonProtocol.scala:428)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$$Lambda$4808/1475607995.apply(Unknown Source)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.accumulableInfoToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:428)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.$anonfun$accumulablesToJson$4(JsonProtocol.scala:420)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$$Lambda$4204/1507248734.apply(Unknown Source)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.accumulablesToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:420)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.taskInfoToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:412)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.taskEndToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:171)
  at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.sparkEventToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.rpc.app.RpcAppEvent$.encodeEvent(RpcAppEvent.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.rpc.app.RpcAppEvent$.apply(RpcAppEvent.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.rpc.app.RpcAppEventQueue.enqueue(RpcAppEventQueue.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.rpc.app.RpcAppListener.addToEventQueue(RpcAppListener.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.rpc.app.RpcAppListener.onEvent(RpcAppListener.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.rpc.util.SingleHandlerListener.onTaskEnd(SingleHandlerListener.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus.doPostEvent$(SparkListenerBus.scala:28)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:120)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll$(ListenerBus.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.super$postToAll(AsyncEventQueue.scala:127)

Spark config:
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=9
spark.executor.cores=2
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=1
spark.executor.instances=8
spark.shuffle.service.client.class=org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleClient
spark.driver.maxResultSize=1g
spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=1073741824
spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin=true
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=300s
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Detwlogger.component=sparkexecutor -DlogFilter.filename=SparkLogFilters.xml -DpatternGroup.filename=SparkPatternGroups.xml -Dlog4jspark.root.logger=INFO,console,RFA,ETW,Anonymizer -Dlog4jspark.log.dir=/var/log/sparkapp/${user.name} -Dlog4jspark.log.file=sparkexecutor.log -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/usr/hdp/current/spark3-client/conf/executor-log4j2.properties -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC
spark.driver.cores=1
spark.driver.memory=**2g**
spark.executor.memory=9g
spark.driver.memoryOverhead=**384**
spark.executor.memoryOverhead=921


There are 9 executors and 919 tasks total.
Code is executed within:
df.rdd.foreachPartition

With some int and string accumulators (string accumulators controlled to not grow indefinitely)
After each task completed I can see this log (for each task it's approx. ~60000-62000, no outliers):
INFO Executor [Executor task launch worker for task 258.0 in stage 59.0 (TID 4666)]: Finished task 258.0 in stage 59.0 (TID 4666). 61394 bytes result sent to driver

And Spark fails with OOM after ~270/919 tasks completed.
My understanding is that it fails when Executors communicate their state to Driver and Driver is accumulating this info doing all JSON stuff.
However, 270 * 60 Kb ~ 15 Mb and shouldn't kill Driver with OOM, unless it is copied multiple times internally.
Simplest solution here is to add memory to driver, but I'm wondering how can I investigate this OOM further to prove my theory that OOM occurred due to Executor -> Driver communication
Thanks!

Objects in memory could be using a lot more space than the the pure data bytes. Or big arrays/strings copied around easily use too much memory. Try analyzing the heap dump.

You may need to supply additional runtime flags to the entire program (the Java Runtime) when you start it. I suggest reading this post on the two flags that matter most: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvm
